# Cant pass data $.ajax to ashx handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, handlers

I've this piece of code that calls my handler, but i cant receive data in my handler, can you help?

//CLIENT SIDE

```
$("#saveChanges").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../handlers/adminSaveResults.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{ 'pinNovo': '" + "123456" + "' }",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Dados Guardados! ;)");
        },
        error: function (data) { alert("ERRO: " + data.status); },
        timeout: 15000
    });
}
```

//SERVER SIDE (adminSaveResults.ashx)

```
                try
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                    context.Response.Write(context.Request.QueryString["pinNovo"].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception msg)
                {
                    context.Response.Write(msg.Message);
                }
```

And the result is allways the same, i've tried other options but allways with the same result: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending data as JSON but are trying to read through querystring.

Use like this

```
$("#saveChanges").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../handlers/adminSaveResults.ashx?pinNovo=123456",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Dados Guardados! ;)");
        },
        error: function (data) { alert("ERRO: " + data.status); },
        timeout: 15000
    });
}
```

Now you can receive data in query string.

Comment: it worked, but cant i use the data propertie that is in $.ajax ??

Comment: and is it save to use like this?

Comment: Yes, then you need to read data from context.Request.Form["pinNovo"].

Comment: Use       data: { "pinNovo": "123456" }    . Do not use data: "{ 'pinNovo': '" + "123456" + "' }" in ajx method

Comment: Use data: { pinNovo: "123456" }.I have just verified it and it was working. Do not use " before and after pinNovo